# flycheck doesn't check

Tags: flycheck

i installed and enabled flycheck but it doesn't find errors in my software (c code), errors that i deliberately inserted to test it

instead it works on a new minimal c file (also not saved)

what could be the problem? thanks in advance

emacs version

> GNU Emacs 24.5.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.18.6)  of
>   2015-12-14 on binet, modified by Debian

flycheck version

> Flycheck version: 0.26snapshot (package: 20151212.411)

flycheck-verify-setup

> Syntax checkers for buffer formelement.c in c-mode:
>
> c/c++-clang
>       - predicate:  nil
>       - executable: Not found
>
> c/c++-gcc
>       - predicate:  t
>       - executable: Found at /usr/bin/gcc
>
> c/c++-cppcheck
>       - predicate:  nil
>       - executable: Not found
>
> Flycheck Mode is enabled.

Comment: Without seeing the code it's hard to tell what goes wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

it needs to add each include path to flycheck-gcc-include-path (in my case glib cflags taken from pkg-config)

otherwise flycheck says nothing (no error)